# Fill a pandas column according to the value of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill a column: if the value of a row A is contained in the row of column B, then fill the column C with the value A

**I tried:**

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([{'A': "a", 'B': ["a"], 'C': ''},
                       {'A': "b", 'B': ["a", "b"], 'C': ''},
                       {'A': "d", 'B': [], 'C': ''},
                       {'A': "c", 'B': ["d", "e"], 'C': ''}])

def fill_row(df):

    if df["B"].str.contains(df["A"], regex = False):
        val = df["A"]
    else:
        val = ""

    return val

df['C'] = df.apply(fill_row, axis=1)
```

**My output:**

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

**Good output:**

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([{'A': "a", 'B': ["a"], 'C': 'a'},
                       {'A': "b", 'B': ["a", "b"], 'C': 'b'},
                       {'A': "d", 'B': [], 'C': ''},
                       {'A': "c", 'B': ["d", "e"], 'C': ''}])
```

Comment: In `fill_row(df)` you are trying to convert a list to string at `if df["B"].str.contains(df["A"], regex = False)`. Rather, try simply  `if df["A"] in df["B"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in` statemenet for test values in list:

```
def fill_row(df):

    if df["A"] in df['B']:
        val = df["A"]
    else:
        val = ""

    return val

df['C'] = df.apply(fill_row, axis=1)
print (df)
   A       B  C
0  a     [a]  a
1  b  [a, b]  b
2  d      []   
3  c  [d, e]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way about it is a list comprehension :

```
df['C'] = [a  if a in b else c for a,b,c in zip(df.A,df.B, df.C)]

    A   B       C
0   a   [a]     a
1   b   [a, b]  b
2   d   []  
3   c   [d, e]
```